# How to change production build static folder path in a React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, build, create-react-app

I have a **React** project on which I ran `npm run build` and it made a production build for me. The problem is that it gives me the following stylesheet injected into the `index.html`

```
<script src="./static/js/5.a4bfdba9.chunk.js"></script>
```

As you can see, the path set is `./static/js/`

But I want the path to be set to `./static/dashboard/js/5.a4bfdba9.chunk.js`

I can't figure out where or what to change to ensure every time I run the build, it takes the path specified by me instead of the default path?

**Note:** I looked at `"homepage": "."` attribute in `package.json` but changing this will only append a path before `/static/js/`

Comment: Which utility did you use to start the project? Create react app? Are you using typescript or just JavaScript?

Comment: @JensBodal I use `create react app`

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: @JensBodal No it's a simple react project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use custom build output folder when using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495658/use-custom-build-output-folder-when-using-create-react-app)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:**

You will need to update the webpack config to achieve this. There are multiple ways to do that:

1. react-scripts eject (not recommended)
2. patch-package
3. react-app-rewired

I am providing steps for `patch-package`.
You need to make changes to the file `config/webpack.config.js` of react-scripts package. Here is a git diff of changes you need to make:

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js b/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
index 26c2a65..ad29fbd 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
+++ b/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
@@ -212,13 +212,13 @@ module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {
       // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
       // In development, it does not produce real files.
       filename: isEnvProduction
-        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js'
+        ? 'static/dashboard/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js'
         : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/bundle.js',
       // TODO: remove this when upgrading to webpack 5
       futureEmitAssets: true,
       // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
       chunkFilename: isEnvProduction
-        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js'
+        ? 'static/dashboard/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js'
         : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
       // webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
       // It requires a trailing slash, or the file assets will get an incorrect path.
@@ -676,8 +676,8 @@ module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {
         new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
           // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
           // both options are optional
-          filename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
-          chunkFilename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css',
+          filename: 'static/dashboard/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
+          chunkFilename: 'static/dashboard/css/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css',
         }),
       // Generate an asset manifest file with the following content:
       // - "files" key: Mapping of all asset filenames to their corresponding
```

Now if you make these changes to `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js` you will get the files outputted to your desired folder and index.html will have correct paths too.
But the changes in node_modules will be overwritten if you install/uninstall any package. To persist those changes you can use [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package), which will write your changes in node_modules after install.

Here are the steps to setup patch-package, you can read their [readme file](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package#readme) for more details:

1. `yarn add patch-package postinstall-postinstall`
2. Add this in scripts section of package.json:
   `"postinstall": "patch-package"`
3. run patch-package to create a .patch file:
   `npx patch-package some-package`
4. commit the patch file to share the fix with your team
   `git add patches/react-scripts+4.0.3.patch`
   `git commit -m "change output dir structure in react-scripts"`

I have created a [git repository](https://github.com/vaibhavhrt/cra-custom-build-dir-structure) too for your reference.

**Old Answer:**

**Warning:** won't work for moving contents of build folder. Can move the whole build folder only. eg: `mv build/ dist/`

Changing settings of create react app so that it outputs to different folder will be very complicated. But you can move the files after build completes, which is much simple.

In your package.json you have:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "react-scripts build"
```

You can add another script called `postbuild` that does something after the build and will be called by npm/Yarn automatically.

```
"postbuild": "mv build/ dist/"
```

This should move the files to different folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I had to do a little modification to the post build command. I had to create the dashboard folder first. So my final command was `"postbuild": "mkdir build/static/dashboard && mv build/static/js/ build/static/dashboard/js/ && mv build/static/css/ build/static/dashboard/css/"` You may update your answer for the benefit of future readers. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: Hey I can see that its creating the `css` and `js` folders under the `dashboard` folder but in the `index.html`, it still refers to the path `./static/js/5.a4bfdba9.chunk.js`. Do I need to change anything else?

Answer (score 10):

Today there is a better solution. From [hashrocket](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/xtgpx9kssz-set-the-relative-path-of-assets-in-a-cra-app):

When I build my CRA app I get a path for my assets (css, images) that begins with /static. If I deploy my app to `https://something.com/myapp`, then the app will try to access those asset paths at `https://something.com/static/asset.css`. That's not where the asset lives. The asset lives at `https://something.com/myapp/static/asset.css`.

Create React App allows you to change the prefix for a the built assets with the homepage attribute in your `package.json` file.

You could set it to myapp:

```json
"homepage": "/myapp"
```

And then the asset will have the path of `/myapp/static/asset.css`

---

In my case, I made the following changes to my `package.json`:

```json
  "homepage": "/search",
  "build": "react-scripts build && mkdir build/search && mv build/static build/search/static"
```

This is because I had an nginx reverse proxy serving `/search` to a different endpoint, so all my static assets had to be served from `/search/static` instead.

Comment: happy to hear it!

Comment: Thanks for linking hashrocket. It really help me though it does not fixed my issue but gave me some clarity. Kudos!! :)

Answer (score -2):

In case anyone else runs into a similar problem. My issue was that the project name was being prepended to the static path.

So the path was `/{project-name}/static/5.a4bfdba9.chunk.js` instead of  `/static/5.a4bfdba9.chunk.js`

Following the solution provided I came across a note specifying the "public path" was inferred from homepage. In the `package.json` my homepage url included the project name.

**Wrong**
"homepage": "https://{URL}.io/project-name"

**Correct**
"homepage": "https://{URL}.io/project-name"

Removing the project name from this url resolved the issue.

Comment: your wrong and correct are the same url.