React App deployed in github but not showing images
https://github.com/Aarif-Hussain-A-Nassar/Tungstonlabs
providing the github link
here  and also the live link in the github
i tried every methods like providing realtive path and so on also given the repository name with the path also but not use
used some methods from the stackoverflow qns but no use
if somebody knows make changes in github for better understanding for me
WORKS PERFECTLY IN LOCALHOST!!!!!!

Your images are saved in Tungstonlabs/images directory like https://aarif-hussain-a-nassar.github.io/Tungstonlabs/images/2.png
But your website is sending the request to https://aarif-hussain-a-nassar.github.io/images/2.png.
Modify the location of the static file or change the image loading path.
I have no experience using react-scripts, so I can't give you an exact solution, but How to change production build static folder path in a React project? -react-project See this link.

In localhost, the index.html file is located in the root, so even if the image is loaded as /images/XX.png, which is an absolute path, localhost/images/XX.png will be loaded normally. However, because the index.html file of the homepage you deployed is located at https://.../Tungstonlabs, if you load /images/XX.png, https://.../images/XX.png will be loaded. It is. (although I wanted https://.../Tungstonlabs/images/XX.png)

so can you tell me like what will be the "Modify the location of the static file or change the image loading path."

add "homepage": "." in package.json

@AarifHussainANassar However, I haven't tested it myself. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66655025/how-to-change-production-build-static-folder-path-in-a

"homepage": "https://Aarif-Hussain-A-Nassar.github.io/Tungstonlabs", so i have to replace this with "."?

It is said that if you change the homepage value to ".", static files (including images) will always be loaded in a relative path. In other words, it no longer matters where index.html is located.
Test it out. I haven't tried it myself.

okay  i will test it out

not able to resolve it!!!
